# Where is the latest version of ksoap2 jar file for android?

Tags: java, android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I know it sounds like a stupid question, but I've tried to find the latest Ksoap2 jar files on google but to no avail. I think the latest versions are 3+, but so far I have only found deprecated versions of it.

On github:

https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android

There isn't any ksoap2 jar file at all.
Any idea how to get the latest version of the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current ksoap2-android jars are located [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/). For future reference, you can find the repository for the releases in the `pom.xml` (for example, in the current [`3.6.2`](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android/blob/3.6.2/pom.xml#L76) version) and on the project [website](http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/getting-started.html).